# sumifs using range cell - error 1004

Tags: excel, range, formula, cells

i need your help.

if i'm running this code, there are no problem occur ( be attention on *Sheet1.Range("F2:BL6991"))*

```
Colnumber = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    'MsgBox (Colnumber)

     For j = 3 To Colnumber

        For i = 2 To Rownumber
        Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheet1.Range("F2:BL6991"), Sheet1.Range("E2:E6991"), Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))


        Next i

    Next j
```

but i when try to change to this code : ( i change my code from  *Sheet1.Range("F2:BL6991") to Sheet1.Range(cells(2,j+3), cells(6991, j+3)) )*

```
Colnumber = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        'MsgBox (Colnumber)

         For j = 3 To Colnumber

            For i = 2 To Rownumber
            Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheet1.Range(cells(2,j+3), cells(6991, j+3)) , Sheet1.Range("E2:E6991"), Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))


            Next i

        Next j
```

it gave me error 1004.

even when i used this code, it gave me error also :

```
Sheet1.Range(cells(2,6), cells(6991, 6))
```

or

```
Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = varResult
        varResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
                        Arg1:=Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(6991, 6)), _
                        Arg2:=Sheet1.Range("E2:E6991"), _
                        Arg3:=Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))
```

Could you guide me where i do wrong and how to fix it also?

TIA

Comment: (1) Why are you using SUMIFS rather than SUMIF for a single criteria test (2) `F2:BL6991` should be a single column

Comment: i already try and change my code to : `Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheet1.Range("E2:E6991"), Sheet2.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, j + 3), Cells(6991, j + 3))), `. but still give me error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that SUMIF only holds 3 arguments:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

This will work:

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Condition As Range

Set Range1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:BL6991")

Colnumber = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
For j = 3 To Colnumber
    For i = 2 To 10
        Set Condition = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)
        Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range1, Condition)
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: it works...but with little modification as below :

`Dim Range1, Range2 As Range
    Dim Condition As Range

    Set Range1 = Worksheets("3G").Columns(5)

    Colnumber = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    'MsgBox (Colnumber)

    For j = 3 To Colnumber
        k = j + 3
        MsgBox (k)
        Set Range2 = Worksheets("3G").Columns(k)
        For i = 2 To Rownumber
            Set Condition = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)
            Sheet2.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range2, Range1, Condition)

        Next i
    Next j`

thanks for the clue

Comment: @WhisnuragaPutra Please don't edit others' answers with your words included, it distorts the genuineness of the answer. If you want to add something useful which resolves your probelm, add your own answer.